# Why is medcouple in Stata not returning any answer?

Tags: stata

I have imported my csv file from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rupakroy/online-payments-fraud-detection-dataset into Stata.

I did the follwing steps:

```
ssc install medcouple

medcouple(amount)
```

But I receive no output.

[image]

Note that the sample size of variable amount is 6,362,620

Comment: I set a problem with the same size running and broke it because it was not giving results in reasonable time There are many resistant measures of skewness as alternatives.  See Section 7 of https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X211063415

Comment: In my case, I can't go with moment-based measures as I've researched "In the presence of one or more outliers the values of these sample measures can be arbitrarily large". I read the following on Quartile Skewness
"Bowley-Galton quartile definition has several disadvantages. It uses only the central 50% of the data to estimate the skewness. Two different data sets that have the same quartile statistics will have the same quantile skewness, regardless of the shape of the tails of the distribution."
Because of the limitation of these 2 measures, I wanted to use MC.

Comment: @NickCox. Can you advise me which measure of skewness can be more appropriate for my case. Do you think i can still go for QS as measure of skewness. Thanks for the paper also :)

Comment: Sure, you don't want moment-based measures, but the same single measure can **always** arise from different distributions, regardless of whether it is based on moments or quantiles, and I imagine that medcouple is not different. I would look at L-moments, which were beyond the scope of my paper but are implemented in Stata using `lmoments` from SSC.

Comment: @NickCox. Thanks for the help. Seems very good the 'lmoments' in Stata.

Answer (score -1):

You've not presented a reproducible problem. Here is a demonstration that `medcouple` can work.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 automobile data)

. ssc inst medcouple
checking medcouple consistency and verifying not already installed...
installing into C:\Users\Laptop\ado\plus\...
installation complete.

. medcouple mpg


MEDCOUPLE
---------

The medcouple is: .25
```

However, my guess is that you are still waiting for an answer. `medcouple` just crawls very slowly with a dataset that size.

Comment: There is a close flag to indicate non-reproducible questions/problems

Comment: Indeed there is, and you're entitled to use it. The whole of the answer indicates that something informative can be said any way, which is more constructive than just closing. In any case, the nature of the problem is that it's hard to demonstrate here, as we could not expect the OP to post a massive dataset. There are ways round that too, but I stop there. In summary, not giving a reproducible example makes this a weak question, but not utterly impossible.